# How to limit the query pattern in Tableau

Tags: mysql, sql-server, tableau-api

all,

I am using Tableau 9.0 to do data analysis and want other users to only run the PERMITTED pattern of queries. How could I configure the tableau to only run some special pattern of queries? Could I use template with regex or Custom SQL query to do that?

e.g. I have one table named 't1', with fields '_id', 'name', 'age','grade'..
I  want other users to only run the queries which ALWAYS contains field '_id', such as 'select name from t1 where id=1;', 'select count(*) from t1 group by _id;', 'select grade from t1 where _id in (1, 2, 3)...'

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The filtering capabilities in Tableau are focused on the contents of the data, rather than the query itself (indeed, Tableau is modeled so that you're abstracted away from the underlying queries in most cases). You can used data source filters to define permitted records that users can use, enforcing some security restrictions on data retrieval. That being said, I've found it's almost always easier/more robust to provide the filtering within the upstream data repository (RBAC in MS-SQL, for instance).

Here's the help section on Data Source Filtering. http://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/online/mac/en-us/help.htm#filtering_datasource.html